# Problem with SQL DEVELOPER: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi I Have been trying to solve this error with happens 3 days ago. I try everything with is on internet, and I still getting the same error.

If you can help me with this, due to I'm quite new on this, I thanks you a lot:

The file tnsnames.ora is this:

```
LISTENER_XE =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )   
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

The Listener.ora is this:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )

)
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
      (SID_DESC =
         (SID_NAME = XE)
         (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
       )
     )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

And the lsnrctl status is this:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 20-ABR-2020 20:16:51

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                20-ABR-2020 20:02:42
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 14 min. 9 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\DESKTOP-7AC259Q\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

I guess that as the Listener works, the problem must be on the "tnsnames.ora" file, but I don't find the possible error.

1000 Thank you for advance!

UPDATE: I realize when I try to make the tnsping to the services xe, that they don't response:

```
C:\Users\manul>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 21-ABR-2020 11:45:53

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (0 msec)
```

Beside I checked that I can to connect to the database via cmd, so the problem is in the conection, and not in database I guess.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mar Abr 21 11:55:40 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: hr
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL>
```

Now I'm really confuse due to I restart the service XE, and I put on automatic, but nothing change.

Comment: Please show the connection descriptor from sql developer.

Comment: Do you mean the setup of the differents parameters of the conections right?

Comment: The hosname: localhost; Port:1521; SID:xe

Comment: your listener log shows that it's not listening for service XE - is the XE database up and running?

Comment: I don't know but I guees that it don't. In that case, how can I make that XE get up and running?

Comment: As it is MS Windows, go to Start - All programs - find Oracle XE - click the "Start database" button. Or, go to Services (in Control panel's Administrative tools) and start the "OracleServiceXE" service; or, even better, set it to start up *automatically* (as well as OracleXETNSListener service).

Comment: That It's exacly what I do, I correct the names tnsnames.ora file, and restart the XE service, but doesn't works. However, one week ago, I have the same error and I solved it like this.